# Why the method describeSubnets in AmazonEC2ClientWrapper results in the AuthFailure?

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking

Probably, the problem is in VPC/security groups/policies, what should I pay attention to?

The stack is as follows:

```
com.veracode.security.logging.SecureExceptionWrapper: AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 401; Error Code: AuthFailure; Request ID: 6777ec95-8167-4311-b46e-e40ce7043034)
com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1640)
com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1304)
com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1058)
com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:743)
com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:717)
com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:699)
com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:667)
com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:649)
com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:513)
com.amazonaws.services.ec2.AmazonEC2Client.doInvoke(AmazonEC2Client.java:13611)
com.amazonaws.services.ec2.AmazonEC2Client.invoke(AmazonEC2Client.java:13587)
com.amazonaws.services.ec2.AmazonEC2Client.executeDescribeSubnets(AmazonEC2Client.java:8308)
com.amazonaws.services.ec2.AmazonEC2Client.describeSubnets(AmazonEC2Client.java:8284)
com.company.was.jobservice.utils.ec2.AmazonEC2ClientWrapper.describeSubnets(AmazonEC2ClientWrapper.java:112)
```

Also I check the policies, one of the policies is :
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:Describe*",
                "ec2:CreateTags"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}

Will this policy cover describeSubnets?

Answer (score 0):

The problem doesn't seem to be linked to VPC or security groups.

You need to (1) correctly [configure your credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html) and (2) have the correct IAM policy to call `describeSubnets`, something like:

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "ec2:DescribeSubnets"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

You might want to be more restrictive on the `Resource` field to narrow it to specific subnets.

Comment: Added the policy - does it cover  DescribeSubnets?

Comment: Yes, it does. Have a look at the credentials configuration and confirm that your are using the credentials of the user/role having the policy you are showing.

Comment: Also check your system time, as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27685288/aws-was-not-able-to-validate-the-provided-access-credentials